# Accessing Firefox cache from an XPCOM component

Tags: c++, firefox, xpcom, gecko

Does anybody know how to **get local path** of file cached by Firefox based on its `URL` from an `XPCOM` component?

Answer (score 4):

To access cached items, new cache session must be created using *createSession* method provided in *[nsICacheService](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/xpcomref/ifaces/nsICacheService.html)*. This method creates *[nsICacheSession](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/xpcomref/ifaces/nsICacheSession.html)*
object. Information about cache item can be obtained using *openCacheEntry* method of the session object (method return *[nsICacheEntryDescriptor](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/xpcomref/ifaces/nsICacheEntryDescriptor.html)*). To read data user must open input stream using *openInputStream* method of the cache entry object.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it is possible to create a cache entry. Another words, is there a method like createCacheEntry()? I have a file on disk which I would like to add to Firefox cache

Thanks.