# Browser Cache API for non IE browsers

Tags: firefox, caching, xpcom, wininet, gecko

IE has WinInet API, such as GetUrlCacheEntryInfo, to read and manipulate IE browser cache.

Is there a similar API for non IE browsers such as Firefox or Chrome? If so where can I get more info?

Thanks

Update:

According to following ([Accessing Firefox cache from an XPCOM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453/accessing-firefox-cache-from-an-xpcom-component)) the WinInet function GetUrlCacheEntryInfo() can be accomplished by nsICacheSession.openCacheEntry() to get nsICacheEntryDescriptor. Is there an equivalent WinInet function CreateUrlCacheEntry() which will create a cache entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that calling nsICacheSession.openCacheEntry() with ACCESS_READ_WRITE will create the cache entry.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it. All solutions I've seen brute-force it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/firefoxbrowsercache.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453/accessing-firefox-cache-from-an-xpcom-component explains

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and here it is for Chrome:
http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/disk-cache

Answer (score 0):

for web page usage, you may want to view the YUI storage utility

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/